# Replacing unknown characters in a string Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I define characters(in a LIST or a STRING), and have any other characters replaced with.. lets say a '?'

Example:

```
strinput = "abcdefg#~"
legal = '.,/?~abcdefg' #legal characters
while i not in legal:
    #Turn i into '?'
print output
```

Comment: Will any of the characters you care to keep be non-ASCII?

Comment: "My question is, how can I define characters(in a LIST or a STRING), and have any other characters replaced with.. lets say a '?'" Why would you use a list or string? Seems like a great job for a dict, if you were going to take such a simple approach. Undefined? Catch a `KeyError` and deal with it.

Comment: How can i use a dictionary if i do not know the characters that i cannot use? @Two-BitAlchemist

Comment: I thought you were saying you defined your own encoding of sorts, meaning you're mapping "legal" input characters to defined output characters. That sounds like a perfect job for a dict to me, and thus an illegal character would be the case where you looked in the dict but it was not there (`try ... except KeyError: print('this character is not defined')`)

Comment: For now, the only characters I will be keeping are "a-zA-Z0-9 and ~!@#$%^&*()_+|-=\{}[]:";'<>?,./" but I would prefer to be able to edit that list quickly in case I need to allow more characters, or remove characters. For example, i CAN NOT allow the usage of ' ` ' in my code because of the way i generate my binary/hex.  @mark-ransom

Comment: I am using a dict for conversion yes. But i want to turn all unknown characters into a '?' before the conversion. @Two-BitAlchemist

Comment: @AustinSmith Why does that have to happen _before_ the conversion?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist because i need the character to be turned into a '?' so that i can convert them as if they were a '?'

Comment: @AustinSmith It sounds like you are trying to do that so that you know in advance which ones can't be converted. You don't need to know in advance. You just need to catch a `KeyError` for whichever ones are not in your conversion dict.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist What i am doing is _encrypting_ files. I HAVE to have unknown characters set as something i have DEFINED _before_ they get encrypted. Else, they break my description code because the random unconverted characters get put between my binary characters. I also do not want to delete then because i want the user to know there was a illegal character there.

Comment: @AustinSmith That doesn't preclude using my suggestion, and you probably should not be [rolling your own encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) if that's really what you mean.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Its message/text file encryption. Using Dynamic character replacement and horizontal character shifting. Right now i'm just trying to put my concept to code. I will fine tune it later on. This is just a project to help me learn to code better, and to send encrypted messages to friends. i doubt anything will come of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the legal characters in a set then use [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=membership#membership-test-operations) to test each character of the string.  Construct the new string using the [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method and a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

```
>>> s = "test.,/?~abcdefgh"
>>> legal = set('.,/?~abcdefg')
>>> s = ''.join(char if char in legal else '?' for char in s)
>>> s
'?e??.,/?~abcdefg?'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a large file, read in chunks, and apply `re.sub(..)` as below. `^` within a class (square brackets) stands for negation (similar to saying "anything other than")

```
>>> import re
>>> char = '.,/?~abcdefg'
>>> re.sub(r'[^' + char +']', '?', "test.,/?~abcdefgh")
'?e??.,/?~abcdefg?'
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that i will not be editing the file directly, and instead have the contents saved to a string. I edited my question.

Comment: Almost all answers here on StackOverflow are generic. I am sure you can take the idea of `re.sub(..)` further..

Comment: @AustinSmith - this accomplishes what you need.